# Text editing in JSVGCanvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, svg

this is a online svg editing, it have a Text editing, can i do this in JSVGCanvas?

http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1771/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html

Comment: No one know? I am very worry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your JSVGCanvas should display empty SVG like this:

```
DOMImplementation imp = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
DocumentType type = imp.createDocumentType(SVGConstants.SVG_PUBLIC_ID, SVGConstants.SVG_SYSTEM_ID, null);
Document svgDoc = imp.createDocument(SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, "svg", type);
JSVGCanvas canvas = new SVGCanvas(new SVGUserAgentAdapter(), true, true);
canvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
canvas.setSVGDocument(svgDoc);
```

Add a mouse and key listeners for getting x, y and text. After create a text element:

```
Element textElement = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
textElement.setTextContent(text);
svgDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(textElement);
```

Selection text is provided by textSelectionManager from JSVGCanvas:

```
canvas.getTextSelectionManager()
```